# how can i solve this problem>> TclError: Item 236716 already exists

Tags: tkinter, treeview, tkintertable

I want to display my csv data in a tkinter table, but when i run, it shows an error!

TclError: Item 236716 already exists

how can i fix it please?

```
csvreader=csv.reader(file)
l1=[] #liste des en-têtes de colonne
l1=next(csvreader) #column header
rset=[row for row in csvreader]  #liste des lignes de données

table=ttk.Treeview(fenetre,selectmode='browse') #mode navigation
table.place(x =550, y = 150, width=600,height=400)
table['height']=5
table['show']='headings'


table['columns']=l1

for i in l1:
    table.column(i, width=100,anchor='c')
    table.heading(i, text=i)

for j in rset:  #ajout des donnees
    v=[r for r in j] #il cree une liste dans j
    table.insert('', 'end', iid=v[0],values=v)
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354572/tkinter-tclerror-item-1-already-exists-with-tkinter-treeview